# rails bootstrap modal window modal-lg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I made a simple large  modal window in my rails project.
Here is the code:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog  modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">  title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The code is copypasted from here: [w3cschools](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_lg&stacked=h)
I also tried it to work in jsfiddle it works well.
But on my website this modal doesn't get css 
from `modal-lg`.
 I also issued some wired problems with bootstrap responsive grids earlier and decided to use pure.css grid  cause I didn't have enough time to dig deeper. So it feels right now like I have some problems with including bootstrap.
This is part of my  gem file where I include bootstrap:

```
gem 'rails', '4.0.2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem "font-awesome-rails"
```

So how do I fix this? ( I can make a simple demo page and push it to heroku to show you that modal doesn't work properly, if it will help

Upd: so okay, you can see the example here: [link](https://arcane-beyond-35849.herokuapp.com/about). Check it in web inspector. And check w3c modal window in web inspector to see that on my website it doesn't really get css for modal-lg

Comment: Your like is to: `http://0.0.0.0:3000/about`

Comment: 5 sec sorry stupid me

Comment: @DickieBoy check again, please. I 've updated link